# stm32f103C8T6 - Controlling a stepper motor via DM422C (Digital Stepping Drive) - Assembler ARM7

Tags: assembly

```
.syntax unified

  .text
  .global __main
  .global function
  .thumb_func

  .equ  RCC_BASE,  0x40021000
  .equ  RCC_APB2_ENR,   0x40021018       // STM32f103C8T6 - Adresse von RCC_APB2ENR - 0x18

  .equ  GPIOC_BASE, 0x40011000      // GPIOC-Basisadresse nach "memory-map", Datenblatt
  .equ  GPIOC_CRH,  0x40011004      // GPIOC-BASE + 0x04 ist das Konfigurationsregister

  .equ  GPIOA_BASE, 0x40010800
  .equ  GPIOA_CRL,  0x40010800

  .equ  GPIO_ODR,   0x4001080C

  .equ  GPIOCEN, 1 << 4     // Seite 141, Referenz-Dokumentation
  .equ  GPIOAEN, 1 << 2     //

  .equ  CRH_OUT_SET_1,  0 << 23
  .equ  CRH_OUT_SET_2,  0 << 22
  .equ  CRH_OUT_SET_3,  1 << 21
  .equ  CRH_OUT_SET_4,  0 << 20 // Von unten nach oben: MODE1, MODE0, CNF1, CNF0 festlegen - (Referenz-Handbuch, Seite 161)

  .equ  CRL_OUT_SET_1_PA4,  0 << 19
  .equ  CRL_OUT_SET_2_PA4,  0 << 18
  .equ  CRL_OUT_SET_3_PA4,  1 << 17
  .equ  CRL_OUT_SET_4_PA4,  0 << 16

  .equ  CRL_OUT_SET_1_PA3,  0 << 15
  .equ  CRL_OUT_SET_2_PA3,  0 << 14
  .equ  CRL_OUT_SET_3_PA3,  1 << 13
  .equ  CRL_OUT_SET_4_PA3,  0 << 12

  .equ  CRL_OUT_SET_1_PA2,  0 << 11
  .equ  CRL_OUT_SET_2_PA2,  0 << 10
  .equ  CRL_OUT_SET_3_PA2,  1 << 9
  .equ  CRL_OUT_SET_4_PA2,  0 << 8  // Von unten nach oben: MODE1, MODE0, CNF1, CNF0 festlegen - Konfiguration für PA2, PA3, PA4 einstellen


  .equ  LED_BLUE,   1 << 13 // PC13 - Programm-Kontroll-LED

  .equ  PA2_PUL,    1 << 2
  .equ  PA3_DIR,    1 << 3
  .equ  PA4_ENA,    1 << 4

  .equ  DELAY_TIME, 1000000


//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  __main:

  // Setzen der Uhr im Programm
  LDR   R0,=RCC_APB2_ENR
  LDR   R1,[R0]
  ORR   R1,GPIOAEN
->  ORR R1,GPIOCEN
  STR   R1,[R0]         // Absatz beschreibt das Freischalten der Uhr mit dem Bus für Port A und C

  LDR   R0,=GPIOC_CRH
  LDR   R1,[R0]
  LDR   R2,=(CRH_OUT_SET_1|CRH_OUT_SET_2|CRH_OUT_SET_3|CRH_OUT_SET_4)

  ORR   R1,R2

  STR   R1,[R0]         // Konfiguration-Register setzen

  LDR   R2,=GPIO_ODR    // ODR-Register wird in R2 geladen, PROGRAMM-KONTROLL-LED

  LDR   R4,=GPIOA_CRL
  LDR   R5,[R4]
->  LDR R6,=(CRL_OUT_SET_1_PA2|CRL_OUT_SET_2_PA2|CRL_OUT_SET_3_PA2|CRL_OUT_SET_4_PA2|CRL_OUT_SET_1_PA3|CRL_OUT_SET_2_PA3|CRL_OUT_SET_3_PA3|CRL_OUT_SET_4_PA3|CRL_OUT_SET_1_PA4|CRL_OUT_SET_2_PA4|CRL_OUT_SET_3_PA4|CRL_OUT_SET_4_PA4)

  ORR   R5,R6

  STR   R5,[R4]         //  Konfigurations-Register setzen

  LDR   R6,=GPIO_ODR    // ODR-Register wird in R6 geladen, SCHRITTMOTOR

->  MOV R5,#PA3_DIR
  STR   R5,[R6]
->  MOV R5,#PA4_ENA
  STR   R5,[R6]


  function:

    Blink:

    MOV R1,#LED_BLUE
    STR R1,[R2]

->    MOV   R5,#PA2_PUL
    STR R5,[R6]

    LDR R3,=#DELAY_TIME

    BL  delay1

    MOV R1,#0
    STR R1,[R2]

    MOV R5,#0
    STR R5,[R6]

    LDR R3,=#DELAY_TIME

    BL  delay1
    B   Blink

    delay1:
    SUBS R3,R3,#1
    BNE delay1   // BNE, BX
    BX  LR
```

(1) Could you check some code-passages in ASSEMBLER ARMv7 for me? I marked relevant semantic lines with an arrow, -> .

(2) Could you give your opinions regarding the code in the discussion?

(3) Is there a common understanding of programming regarding definitions and declarations, sub-programmes etc.? Do you know a fundamental programmers book beside the official documentation for ARMv7?

[image]

Comment: Any support would be appreciated ... especially regarding the ASSEMBLER-part...

Comment: Support is expressively wished ...

Comment: Cross posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77512215/stm32f103c8t6-controlling-a-stepper-motor-via-dm422c-digital-stepping-drive).

Answer (score 2):

> common understanding of programming regarding definitions and declarations, sub-programmes

Carl Burch offers a fair
[summary](http://www.cburch.com/books/armsub)
of calling conventions, which supplements the ARM documentation.

---

## citations

References to page 141 or 161 are helpful and I thank you for them.

But those references seem to suggest I should visit your cubicle
and flip to that page.
It would be more helpful to give full title of
the "Reference Handbook" with its author(s),
and *much* more helpful to offer its URL.

---

## long line

```
  LDR R6,=(CRL_OUT_SET_1_PA2|CRL_OUT_SET_2_PA2|CRL_OUT_SET_3_PA2|CRL_OUT_SET_4_PA2|CRL_OUT_SET_1_PA3|CRL_OUT_SET_2_PA3|CRL_OUT_SET_3_PA3|CRL_OUT_SET_4_PA3|CRL_OUT_SET_1_PA4|CRL_OUT_SET_2_PA4|CRL_OUT_SET_3_PA4|CRL_OUT_SET_4_PA4)
```

There *must* be some better way to express that,
which involves line wrapping.

Minimally, OR those together to define a single constant,
and load R6 with *that*.
Maybe call it `CRL_OUT_SET_1234_PA234`.

---

## use a constant expression

This this works but seems odd:

```
  ORR   R1, GPIOAEN
  ORR   R1, GPIOCEN
```

It would be simpler to just

```
  ORR   R1, GPIOAEN | GPIOCEN
```

---

## busy wait

This code makes me sad:

```
delay1:
    SUBS R3, R3, #1
    BNE delay1       // BNE, BX
    BX  LR
```

It's too bad we can't have an
[ISR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_handler)
run the LED blinking code every N milliseconds.

Or at least busy wait on a TODR (time of day register)
ticking over to some millisecond value we're awaiting.

The current code iterates a million times in a tight loop,
with no indication in the source code about

- what clock rate we believe the code will be deployed on
- what conversion factor would go from DELAY_TIME to SI seconds

Deploying on new hardware, or same hardware with an altered clock rate,
would require more manual testing / tweaking than necessary.
Document the details, so we can make predictions about how
new hardware would execute the current code.

---

This code appears to achieve its design goals.

I would not be willing to accept maintenance tasks on it.
I would be willing to delegate maintenance tasks to
colleagues who know the secret handshake about where
to find Referenz-Dokumentation, and have a working knowledge
of both German and ARMv7.